# Column moving in Oracle Pl/Sql with for loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

For example, I want to move my 2 Column between for example KW_01 (dropdown) and KW_03 (dropdown) to between KW_04 (dropdown) and KW_06 (dropdown). I have 53 column in a table. I wrote code (see below) but unfortunately it does not work properly. He does that when I start a code.

**Unexpected results:**

```
Outer Loop counter is kw_04 Inner Loop counter is 1
Outer Loop counter is kw_04 Inner Loop counter is 2
Outer Loop counter is kw_04 Inner Loop counter is 3
Outer Loop counter is kw_05 Inner Loop counter is 1
Outer Loop counter is kw_05 Inner Loop counter is 2
Outer Loop counter is kw_05 Inner Loop counter is 3
Outer Loop counter is kw_06 Inner Loop counter is 1
Outer Loop counter is kw_06 Inner Loop counter is 2
Outer Loop counter is kw_06 Inner Loop counter is 3
```

```
DECLARE 
  plsql VARCHAR2(500);
BEGIN
  For i in (SELECT column_id
              FROM alsi_bedarfsplanung unpivot(column_value FOR column_id IN("KW_01", "KW_02", "KW_03", "KW_04", "KW_05", "KW_06"))
             WHERE column_id BETWEEN :drp1 AND :drp2
               and id = 1)
  LOOP
    FOR o in (SELECT column_value
                FROM alsi_bedarfsplanung unpivot(column_value FOR column_id IN("KW_01", "KW_02", "KW_03", "KW_04", "KW_05", "KW_06"))
               WHERE column_id BETWEEN :drp3 AND :drp4
                 and id = 1)
    LOOP
      plsql := ' UPDATE ALSI_BEDARFSPLANUNG SET ' || i.column_id || ' = ' ||
               o.column_value || ' where ID = 1 ';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

[My DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggPu3.png)

What i want,

```
Outer Loop counter is kw_04 Inner Loop counter is 1//(KW_1 Value)
Outer Loop counter is kw_05 Inner Loop counter is 2//(KW_2 Value)
Outer Loop counter is kw_06 Inner Loop counter is 3//(KW_3 Value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way you're looping within a loop; what you actually need to do is identify the columns to update to and from separately, and then loop over each set of columns to do the updates.

Even better would be to do all the work in a single update, like so:

```
-- should error with "Invalid columns specified" due to final proc call,
-- but should update the two rows accordingly
DECLARE
  TYPE col_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30) INDEX BY pls_INTEGER;
  v_cols_to_update_arry col_array;
  v_cols_update_from_arry col_array;
  PROCEDURE update_cols (p_id IN INTEGER,
                         p_drp1 IN VARCHAR2,
                         p_drp2 IN VARCHAR2,
                         p_drp3 IN VARCHAR2,
                         p_drp4 IN VARCHAR2)
  IS
    v_sql CLOB := 'UPDATE alsi_bedarfsplanung SET '||CHR(10);
  BEGIN
    SELECT column_id
    BULK COLLECT INTO v_cols_to_update_arry
    FROM   alsi_bedarfsplanung
    UNPIVOT (column_val FOR column_id IN (kw_01, kw_02, kw_03, kw_04, kw_05, kw_06, kw_07, kw_08))
    WHERE  column_id BETWEEN p_drp1 AND p_drp2
    AND    id = p_id;

    SELECT column_id
    BULK COLLECT INTO v_cols_update_from_arry
    FROM   alsi_bedarfsplanung
    UNPIVOT (column_val FOR column_id IN (kw_01, kw_02, kw_03, kw_04, kw_05, kw_06, kw_07, kw_08))
    WHERE  column_id BETWEEN p_drp3 AND p_drp4
    AND    id = p_id;

    IF v_cols_to_update_arry.count > 0
       AND v_cols_update_from_arry.count > 0
       AND v_cols_to_update_arry.count = v_cols_update_from_arry.count THEN

      FOR i IN 1..v_cols_to_update_arry.count
      LOOP
        if i = 1 then 
          v_sql := v_sql || '  ' || v_cols_to_update_arry(i) || ' = ' || v_cols_update_from_arry(i);
        else
          v_sql := v_sql || ',' || CHR(10) || '  ' || v_cols_to_update_arry(i) || ' = ' || v_cols_update_from_arry(i);
        end if;
      END LOOP;

      v_sql := v_sql || chr(10) || 'where id = :p_id';

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING p_id;

    ELSE
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Invalid columns specified');
    END IF;
  END update_cols;
BEGIN
  update_cols (p_id => 1,
               p_drp1 => 'KW_04',
               p_drp2 => 'KW_06',
               p_drp3 => 'KW_01',
               p_drp4 => 'KW_03');

  COMMIT;

  update_cols (p_id => 2,
               p_drp1 => 'KW_05',
               p_drp2 => 'KW_08',
               p_drp3 => 'KW_01',
               p_drp4 => 'KW_04');

  COMMIT;

  update_cols (p_id => 1,
               p_drp1 => 'KW_01',
               p_drp2 => 'KW_02',
               p_drp3 => 'KW_05',
               p_drp4 => 'KW_05');

END;
/
```

This works by fetching each list of columns into a separate array, looping over the arrays to build up the list of columns being updated, before concatenating that into the update statement.

[Here's a demo of it working](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7a1a4e00af5518816d914d2210f29c09)

Comment: If this is to be run regularly, take the procedure inside the anonymous block in my answer and create it as a proper procedure (ideally within a package).